# Conditionally grab a parameter from a URL

Tags: php, variables, url-parameters

In PHP, I have a webpage: `http://www.example.com/index.php?param=val&param2=val2&so_on=so_on`.

How can I get `param`'s value and put it in `$variable` only if the parameter is defined in the URL? Otherwise, I want to set `$variable` to a default value like `123456789`. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a ternary and it will always be set as you asked

```
$var = (isset($_GET['param'])) ? $_GET['param'] : '123456789';
```